# Querying for object based on property of inside object

Tags: c#, linq

I have some objects stored in a LiteDB database. I'm trying to get a result of all CostBasisTradeSessionObjects that include Marked objects with a particular name, MarkedNameString. I find the Marked object easily enough, but I dont now how to query for object in object.

```
public string Marked
{
public ObjectId MarkedId { get; set; }
public String Name { get; set; }
}

public class CostBasisTradeSessionObject
{
public ObjectId CostBasisTradeSessionId { get; set; }
public bool IsActive { get; set; }
public DateTime SessionStarted { get; set; }
public DateTime SessionClosed { get; set; }
public Marked Marked { get; set; }
}

using (var db = new LiteDatabase(@"CostBasesTradeSessionsDatabase.db"))
{
var costBasisTradeSessionObjects = db.GetCollection("costBasisTradeSessionObjects");

        Marked marked = db.GetCollection<Marked>("markeds").Find(Query.EQ("Name", "<MarkedNameString>")).Single();
    }
```

So I try to get an result with CostBasisTradeSessionObject objects that includes the marked object returned in var marked.

So I tried a couple of things

```
var cb = costBasisTradeSessionObjects.Include(x => x.Marked).Equals(marked);
```

and justing jusing the MarkedNameString directory

```
var results = costBasisTradeSessionObjects.(Query.("Marked.name", "MarkedNameString"));
```

or

```
var results = costBasisTradeSessionObjects.Find(x => x.Marked.Name.Equals("MarkedNameString"));
```

but all the things I tried return an empty result or dont work.

Regards

Comment: you should try this,var cb = costBasisTradeSessionObjects.Where(x => x.Marked== "MarkedNameString");

Comment: Try this - var cb = costBasisTradeSessionObjects.Where(x => x.Marked.Equals(marked));

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for the [`Where()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.100).aspx) method. You can filter your search by your `Name` property, and return an IEnumerable of `CostBasisTradeSessionObject`.

```
var results = costBasisTradeSessionObjects
    .Where(x => x.Marked.Name == "MarkedNameString");
```